# Three.js doesn't render when calculating elapsed time

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to render a simple cube which is rotating. To get the same rotationspeed on every machine I calculate the timespan between each frame and use this elapsed value in the rotation.
Basically it's just:

`var elapsed = (timestamp - lastFrameTimestamp)/1000.0; // doesn't show the cube`

But when I'm using this value nothing is shown. Also no error or warning in the console. Outputting the elapsed value to console returns a correct number.

I tried to set the difference to a fixed value and this works fine?!

`var elapsed = 16.665487/1000.0;`

I've created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgy82hcg/3/) for this case. I've tried in Chrome and Firefox, both with the same result.

Has anybody an idea or hint what's causing the problem?

Comment: THREE.clock.getDelta() does the job correct. But I'm still curious why my approach is not working

Comment: `console.log(cube.rotation.x += 0.1 * elapsed)` outputs NaN

Comment: You have to pass Date.now() as an argument to the first animate call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your fiddle is that `timestamp` will be *null* on te first call of `animate`. This in turn leads to `lastFrameTimestamp` and `elapsed`is set to *null*, and finally also the rotation.

From [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) on **requestAnimationFrame**:

> The callback method is passed a single argument, a DOMHighResTimeStamp, which indicates the current time when callbacks queued by requestAnimationFrame begin to fire. Multiple callbacks in a single frame, therefore, each receive the same timestamp even though time has passed during the computation of every previous callback's workload. This timestamp is a decimal number, in milliseconds, but with a minimal precision of 1ms (1000 µs).

So requestAnimationFrame will pass the callback (`animate`) a timestamp, which indicates the current time (the time returned from `performance.now()` ) for when requestAnimationFrame starts to fire callbacks.

So if you want to make use of timestamps in your animation, then you should trigger your animation loop by calling

```
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

not just `animate();`